# How to run OMNeT++ project from Ubuntu terminal

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am using OMNeT++ 5.5.1 installed in Ubuntu 19.04 and it is working fine in IDE environment.

But, I need to run an INET project from Ubuntu terminal. Can anyone suggest me what command to write in terminal if:

- I want to run, for example, INET showcase examples ( `wireless/sensornetwork/omnetpp.ini`)?
- how to see the list of configurations in `omnetpp.ini`?
- and how to choose one specific config and run it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run a simulation from command line do the following:

1. Go to directory of the example you want to start, e.g.:

   ```
   cd showcases/wireless/sensornetwork
   ```
2. To see available config names in `omnetpp.ini` type:

   ```
   opp_run -a
   ```
3. To run selected config (e.g. `LMac`) with GUI type the following command:

   ```
   opp_run -m -u Qtenv -n ../../../src:../..:../../../tutorials:../../../showcases -l ../../../src/INET  omnetpp.ini  -c LMac
   ```
4. To see all runs for selected config type:

   ```
   opp_run -s -c LMac omnetpp.ini -q runs
   ```
5. To start one selected run (e.g. 5) from config (e.g. `LMac`) without GUI type the following command:

   ```
   opp_run -m -u Cmdenv -n ../../../src:../..:../../../tutorials:../../../showcases -l ../../../src/INET  omnetpp.ini  -c LMac -r 5
   ```
6. To start all runs in selected config (e.g. `LMac`) type the following command:

   ```
   opp_run -m -u Cmdenv -n ../../../src:../..:../../../tutorials:../../../showcases -l ../../../src/INET  omnetpp.ini  -c LMac
   ```

The main options for `opp_run`:

- `-u Qtenv` selects graphical view of a simulation (for command environment use `-u Cmdenv`)
- `-n` indicates directories of NED files
- `-l` selects library (here: `libINET.so`)

For more information about running simulations look to [OMNeT++ Manual](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#cha:run-sim).

Comment: Jerzy, if a config has multiple runs (for example statisticLMac has 1000 runs), is there any way to run those automatically one after another with a single command instead of running 1000 times separately? With this above code, actually I have run it 1000 times.

Comment: I have extended my answer - take a look at point 6.